# Select statement taking a long time

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a method like:

```
public JsonResult GetActivities(int id)
{
    var activities = ActivityRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.AreaId == id);

    var jsonData = new {
        rows = activities.Select(q => new {
            Id = q.Id.ToString(),
            q.Descriptor
        }).ToList()
    };

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It works fine but I find the line:

```
var jsonData = new
{ 
    rows = activities.Select(q => new { Id = q.Id.ToString(), q.Descriptor }).ToList()
};
```

takes a very long time to execute.

Could someone please explain to me why this is and is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Looks OK, but we need more information... If you've got SQL profiler, run that and see what query is hitting the database.

Comment: How have you determined that the line takes a long time?

Comment: How many rows are being returned by your query? What is the datatype of the Id? I ask because integers are faster than GUIDs.

Comment: Oh, I put a debugger in and it was taking ages. Actually I think I could have found the problem. The descriptor is complex and built.

Comment: What's the return type of  `ActivityRepository.GetAll()`? Sounds like either a huge amout of records, or eager loading which makes your where clause linq-to-object.

Comment: is there an index on AreaId column in db?

Comment: Return type is IEnumerable<Activity>

Comment: What do you mean by is there an index on AreaId coumn in db?

Comment: Can you please show several rows from `ActivityRepository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely related to your database somehow...

As @geofftnz already have mentioned, then you should use a SQL profiler (ex. [AnjLab Sql Profiler](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/)), and figure out what's going on behind the scenes.

The reason for that it's not taking a long time for:

```
var activities = ActivityRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.AreaId == id);
```

is that it's not sending any queries to the database yet, because of the return type `IEnumerable<Activity>` (lazy).

However when you do:

```
var jsonData = new 
{ 
    rows = activities.Select(q => new 
    { 
        Id = q.Id.ToString(), 
        q.Descriptor 
    }).ToList() 
};
```

it will make up a query, and hit the database at `.ToList()` (eager).

Comment: isn't `activities` an in-memory `IEnumerable<Activity>` at this point?How does the second query hit the database?

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins: Based on the behavior described by the OP, `activities` is almost certainly a query backed by some kind of LINQ provider (most likely tied to a database). The call to `.ToList` forces the query to be evaluated, which is when it hits the database.